Making a Django application enterprise ready
What are the must have features over and above the standard Django deployment checklist one should consider to make the application truly enterprise ready. A few things that I can think of are:

Access Logs
Audit Logs
MFA/SSO for user authentication

I know there can be tons of things on the infrastructure side but I am focussing on the application side stuff only.
Researched on the internet for suggestions but not able to find any authoritative source. Would be great to learn from the experiences of SO members.
